# Modeling a bipyramidal shape

Tags: modeling

I need to draw some bipyramidal shape in Blender (for a nanohub simulation) but I am completely new to this field.

Can anyone help me understand how to model such shape?

Comment: Can you elaborate with an illustration of a "bi-pyramidal shape for nanohub simulation" in question.(and or links)

Comment: https://nanohub.org/tools/ddaplus/session?sess=1430872

Comment: Link above requires registering / logging on.  Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Create the bi-pyramid's base**.

   If the base is going to be a regular polygon, just do: *Add > Circle*, then look for this menu to change the number of vertices. The menu is obtained using <kbd>F6</kbd> in Blender <2.79, or you can just find it in the bottom-left of the Viewport in Blender2.8+

   [image]
2. Jump into *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>), then ***Extrude*** upwards in the *Z* direction (<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd>). If you hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> after starting the extrusion, you can do it by snapping to fixed increments.

   [image]
3. Deselect the top vertices, select the bottom vertices (I used the <kbd>B</kbd> *Box Select* tool), and *Extrude* them downwards

   [image]
4. For both the top and bottom ends: select them, then scale to zero: <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   [image]
5. To finish, select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>), then do *Remove Double Vertices* from the right mouse button menu (Blender 2.8+) or from the <kbd>W</kbd> button menu (<2.79)

   The mesh is already done after step 4, but step 5 gets rid of redundant geometry and open surfaces (which is a requirement for many operations, including boolean, subsurface, 3D printing).

Answer (score 1):

For a general Bi-pyramid ...(working in XY, Z up)

1. Create a circle with the requisite number of sides, and a triangle fan fill.
2. Assign a Mirror modifier in Z, (no clipping or merge at this stage)
3. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> Move the central vertex in Z

[image]

At the creation stage, you can enter the radius numerically, and <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>  + (a number) lets you set the height/2.

Now you can switch on 'Merge' in the modifier, before applying it, if you want to.